# Django Elastic Search: Elastic returns nothing

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I have been studying the documentation and third resources for 2 days, but I cannot solve the problem with the information output.
[image]

my code:
models.py:

```
 class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserAccount, related_name='courses_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,   related_name='category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/', null=True, blank=True)
    video = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Course'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Courses'
```

search_indexes.py:

```
    from elasticsearch_dsl import analyzer
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, Index, fields

from courses import models as courses_models

course_index = Index('courses')
course_index.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=0
)

html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)

class CourseDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')
    name = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
        }
    )
    description = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
        }
    )
    owner = fields.IntegerField(attr='owner_id')
    category = fields.TextField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.TextField(analyzer='keyword'),
        }
    )
    created = fields.DateField()

    class Django:
        model = courses_models.Course
```

serializers.py:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.serializers import DocumentSerializer

from courses import search_indexes as courses_documents
import json

from rest_framework import serializers

class CourseDocumentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    description = serializers.CharField()
    owner = serializers.IntegerField()
    created = serializers.DateField()
    class Meta:

        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'owner',
            'created',
            'category'
        )
```

views.py:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.constants import (
    LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
    LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.filter_backends import (
    FilteringFilterBackend,
    OrderingFilterBackend,
    DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
    CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
)
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import DocumentViewSet

from courses.search_indexes import CourseDocument as courses_documents
from courses.serializers import CourseDocumentSerializer as courses_serializers


class CourseViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
    document = courses_documents
    serializer_class = courses_serializers

    lookup_field = 'id'
    filter_backends = [
        FilteringFilterBackend,
        OrderingFilterBackend,
        DefaultOrderingFilterBackend,
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
    ]

    # Define search fields
    search_fields = (
        'name',
        'description',
    )

    # Filter fields
    filter_fields = {
        'id': {
            'field': 'id',
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_FILTER_RANGE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_GTE,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LT,
                LOOKUP_QUERY_LTE,
            ],
        },
        'name': 'name.raw',
        'description': 'description.raw',
        'owner': {
            'field': 'owner_id',
            'lookups': [
                LOOKUP_QUERY_IN,
            ]
        },
        'created': 'created',
        'category': 'category.raw',
    }

    # Define ordering fields
    ordering_fields = {
        'id': 'id',
        'title': 'title.raw',
        'owner': 'owner_id',
        'created': 'created',
    }

    # Specify default ordering
    ordering = ('id', 'name',)
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from courses import views

app_name = 'courses'

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(
    prefix=r'',
    basename='courses',
    viewset=views.CourseViewSet
)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

i hope u can help me with this problem. at the beginning I thought it was an elastic server connection problem, but tests showed that the connection was successful

Comment: Are you sure that you are using correct url?

Comment: I guess it would be a mistake. + When I disable elasticServer this url gives a connection error

Comment: `/courses/?search=something` returns nothing?

Comment: yea, return [ ]